# org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot list directory:

Tags: apache-camel

Their is a similar posting that claims to have the answer but I'm still getting the error after putting step -> stepwise=false in my camel route.  ->  exception

```
14:35:33,649 WARN  [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFilePollingConsumerPollStrategy] (Camel (camel-1) thread #13 - sftp://myftp:22) Trying to recover by discon
necting from remote server forcing a re-connect at next poll: sftp://myUser@myftp:22
14:35:33,654 WARN  [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] (Camel (camel-1) thread #13 - sftp://myftp:22) Consumer Consumer[sftp://myftp:22?delay
=1h&delete=true&doneFileName=done&password=xxxxxx&sortBy=ignoreCase%3Afile%3Aname&stepwise=false&username=myUser] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[sftp://myftp:22?delay=1h
&delete=true&doneFileName=done&password=xxxxxx&sortBy=ignoreCase%3Afile%3Aname&stepwise=false&username=myUser]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.
GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot list directory: .]: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot list directory: .
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.listFiles(SftpOperations.java:583) [camel-ftp-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.doPollDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:90) [camel-ftp-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.pollDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:52) [camel-ftp-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:119) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114) [camel-core-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: 4: 
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1660) [jsch-0.1.49.jar:]
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1466) [jsch-0.1.49.jar:]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.listFiles(SftpOperations.java:574) [camel-ftp-2.13.2.jar:2.13.2]
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
        at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:308) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream.updateReadSide(Channel.java:344) [jsch-0.1.49.jar:]
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1483) [jsch-0.1.49.jar:]
        ... 14 more
```

here is my route ->

```
sftp://myftp:22?delay
=1h&delete=true&doneFileName=done&password=xxxxxx&sortBy=ignoreCase%3Afile%3Aname&stepwise=false&username=myUser
```

Comment: It looks you ftp server doesn't support to list file in the home directory. 
Can you double check it?

Comment: I used filezilla and connect.. here is the output ->Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command: pwd
Response: Current directory is: "/"
Command: ls
Status: Listing directory /
Status: Directory listing successful

Comment: Also used the command line using linux -> sftp username@myftpserver.com -> once logged in I issued the -> ls -> command and didn't return any errors.  The camel code is running in JBoss which is running on a debian based system.  and the sftp server is a windows machine.  Would this affect anything?

Comment: can you try to use "sftp://myftp:22/" to try it?

Comment: Tried it... and still get the exception

Comment: I have noticed that I get the exception if I set the delay=1h instead of the default delay=500.  Wonder if this has something to do with sftp having to reconnect rather than having a persistent connection over time.

Comment: It turns out to be a connection timeout issue, we could force ftp endpoint to disconnect once it finish the processing to workaround this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is java.io.IOException: Pipe closed.
I just checked the code of camel-ftp, it has the code to check the connection, but it's hard to know if the connection is still opened if we don't send some bytes to server socket.

The solution could be force the ftp client send some ping message to check if the connection is still open.

If you want to set a very long delay for your ftp pulling, the work around way is setting *disconnect* option to be true to force ftp endpoint restart a new connection when it pull the directory again from the FTP server.

I just created [a JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8075) for it.

Comment: I've noticed that if you set delay=500 which is the default rather than 1h you don't get the exception.  I think this has something to do with a persistent connection since the interval is so frequent and the connection stays open.

Comment: seems like setting the route to "disconnect" causes the route to throw an exception.